# how to use XlsxWriter for python

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I'm new to python and am trying to use XlsxWriter to be able to create .xlsx spreadsheets (installation instructions are [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/getting_started.html)). I've installed it with pip as outlined in the installation instructions. I don't get any error messages when running this install.

I'm trying to import XlsxWriter into a `.py` file as outlined in the installation steps but when I try to run this program I am getting the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "newCard.py", line 6, in
>   
>       import xlsxwriter ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlsxwriter'

Here is the code in my file `newCard.py`:

```
import xlsxwriter

print('hello')
```

I know that I don't have any code that is actually using XlsxWriter yet, but because this simple program won't even execute I know there's a problem with trying to import XlsxWriter to begin with. If anyone can help me out with what I need to do to successfully import XlsxWriter into my file I would greatly appreciate it.

As always a correct, clearly explained answer will be marked as accepted and upvoted. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the terminal/program you are using to run your `newCard.py` file? This could happen if it was installed correctly, but your terminal isn't using the updated environment variables which point to where `xlsxwriter` lives

Comment: @SyntaxVoid thanks for the suggestion, i tried closing terminal and opening a new one and I still get the same error. Any idea on how to figure out where my path environment variable should point to so i should be able to import xlsxwriter?

Comment: To make sure that you're installing to the same python you're using to run your script, install the package via `python -m pip install XlsxWriter` then run `newCard.py`